# Android: корейская локализация

Tags: android, java

Есть проблема с корейской локализацией.

Корейский перевод в values-ko не компилируется.

По идее что-то с кодировкой или как..

**android-apt-compiler: [NewTimer] /media/romanzi/KINGSTON/NewTimer/res/values-ko/arrays.xml:12: error: Found text "     " where item tag is expected**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <string-array name="colors_r">
                <item>블랙</item>
                <item>레드</item>
                <item>오렌지</item>
                <item>옐로우</item>
                <item>그린</item>
                <item>블루</item>
                <item>보라</item>
            </string-array>

        <string-array name="color_not_see">
            <item>블랙</item>
            <item>레드</item>
            <item>오렌지</item>
            <item>옐로우</item>
            <item>그린</item>
            <item>블루</item>
            <item>보라</item>
        </string-array>

</resources>
```

С strings.xml таже фигня на строчку с названием программы.
Как это исправить и скомпилить?
Хорошую инструкцию дайте,плиз(

Comment: Все восточные алфавиты, в основном, представлены в 16 байтовой кодировке UTF-16, в отличии от русской и латинской( UTF-8 ), возможно, проблема в этом.

Comment: А вы проверьте, а самом деле ли ваш файл в utf-8.

Comment: В мою убунту первая из корейских строк скопипастилась в utf-8 (это хангыль ?) по 3 байта на корейский символ.

Думаю, остальные такие же.

Comment: открой notepad++ - посмотри Кодировку и поменяй, если че, хотя я тут вижу, что ругается на закрывающийся тэг..

Comment: @avp: может быть, в файле-то и не utf-8, редактор смог опознать кодировку, поэтому и на сайте правильные символы.

Comment: Может и так. Меня больше интересует - это хангыль?

Comment: @avp: ну, символы выглядят как корейские, а сколько у них алфавитов, я не в курсе (по-моему, только один).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совершенно очевидно, что ресурс имеет кодировку не UTF-8 - тут и к бабке ходить не надо. Если у вас нормальный IDE, то он обычно умеет определять реальную кодировку файла. Посмотрите что кажет IDE (например IDEA показывает в строке статуса в правом нижнем углу).

У корейцев в ходу CP-959 (Korean-Hangul), который поддерживается Windows/Linux - скорее всего файл в этой кодировке - потому и показывает корейские символы.

Надо просто взять и перекодировать из CP-959 в UTF-8 и все заработает.